# PostRows API not working with package Microsoft.PowerBi.Api

Tags: c#, api, rest, powerbi

I was able to get the rest APIs working quickly in C#. The code works fine without any errors or exceptions, but the PostRows ( ) method didn't seem to work.

The dataset, table, and columns get created fine, but the rows don't seem to get saved/loaded. I verify by going online to Power BI Service and using a table visualization and adding the table columns to it. It does not show the saved data - see screenshot.

Did the rows not save/load? or am I going to the wrong place to see the data?

Thank you for your help.

using package Microsoft.PowerBi.Api

```
var tableName = "test-table-1";
        var table = new Table()
        {
            Name = tableName,
            Columns = new List<Column>()
            {
                new Column("col1", "string"),
                new Column("col2", "string"),
                new Column("col3", "string")
            }
        };
        var dataset = await PowerBiClient.Datasets.PostDatasetAsync(new CreateDatasetRequest()
        {
            Name = "test-dataset-1",
            DefaultMode = "Push",
            Tables = new List<Table>() {table}
        });
        var postRows = new PostRowsRequest
        {
            Rows = new List<object>()
            {
                new
                {
                    col1 = "sdsdds",
                    col2 = "rtetete",
                    col3 = "werwer2423"
                },
                new
                {
                    col1 = "sd333sdds",
                    col2 = "rtet234ete",
                    col3 = "werw1111er"
                }
            }
        };
        await PowerBiClient.Datasets.PostRowsAsync(dataset.Id, tableName, postRows);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeUH3.png)

Comment: Please also post the code for creating the dataset. What is [the mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdatasetingroup#datasetmode) of the dataset - Push, Streaming, PushStreaming, AsOnPrem?...

Comment: The mode is 'Push' as seen in the code sample in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further investigation revealed that the sdk doesn't handle serialization of anonymous types and silently blanks them out.

As an example, this can be overcome/verified by specifying serialization settings as below.

```
PowerBiClient.SerializationSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver(); //anonymous types serialize to blank {} without this
        await PowerBiClient.Datasets.PostRowsAsync(dataset.Id, tableName, postRows);
```

The sdk doesn't have great documentation - almost none actually.